# How to compile a puppet manifest to obtain all of the catelogs

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, puppet

I am building a small tool that checks on some of the thing done by puppet. I am trying to do a bit of hacking with Puppet to figure out how to take a puppet manifest and produce all of the catalogues for the nodes. I have looked through some of the source code for the parser and compiler haven't been able to get an example to work. Is there a way to do this from the puppet command line tool?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for kicks, my answer will not help you.

If you need this to work, I suggest that you look at [the language puppet library](http://lpuppet.banquise.net). The distributed `puppetresources` binary has an `allnodes` mode that computes catalogs for all nodes defined in the `site.pp` file. It then tests basic stuff (that the catalog compiles, that dependencies are correct [although it is buggy for now], that all users used in `cron`,`file`, etc. are actually defined somewhere, and that sourced files exist on disk).

It is **much** faster than the puppet, and you can use it as a library. That way you can write  any test you want on the produced catalogs.